# No histogram appears in my job results

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

Newbie here - logged in to IBM Q Experience on a MacBook Air with up-to-date OS (macOS Catalina 10.15.7) and Safari browser (14.0).  I can build a circuit in Circuit Composer, select a back-end in Run Settings, run my job on a QPU, and then I see the job appear in the Jobs tab on the right side of the Circuit Composer.  I click on the job and it takes me to the results for the job.  I see the sequence of steps for the job (created, transpiled, validated, in queue, running, completed).  Under that I see Run Details: Back-end, run-mode, shots, status, last update.  Under that I see the circuit which can be displayed as an image, Qasm or Qiskit.  I **do not see the histogram of states anywhere** - nor do I see any menu item that would allow me to download this.  The only downloads I see give me images of the circuit.  How do I get the histogram of states?

![screenshot from IBM Q Experience showing circuit but no histogram of results][image]

Answer (score 1):

What is the status of the job? Can you screenshot and upload the image of what you see.
If the job is completed, then you will see the histogram output at the bottom of the page giving that the number of eigenbasis is not too large.

If your job is completed running, you will be able to see this:

[image]

Note that the job that you submit don't get run right the way as there is a queue so you might have to wait for a bit. But once it is done, you will see the histogram plot. For instance:

[image]

---

If you want, you can run your circuit through the Jupyter notebook environment in IBMQ Experience. The histogram will returned to you once your job is completed. Look at this [notebook tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/representing-qubit-states.html) here.